# Serialization of ' Closure' is not allowed in session_write_close() - DRUPAL 8

Tags: php, session, nginx, drupal

I have problem with session in drupal 8 .

my code is working fine on staging server (apache server ) but not working in live (nginx server )

in my custom module i have  `$_SESSION` (native session keyword )  to store variable

**PHP VERSION:** 7.0.x

I search a lot on google but didn't get any way to hotfix this

```
  The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
    Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in session_write_close() (line 226 of vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).
    session_write_close() (Line: 226)
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->save() (Line: 197)
    Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->save() (Line: 181)
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->save() (Line: 60)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
    Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
    Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
    Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 656)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 20)
```

HINT:Problem with [facebook graph sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) without this its working fine

Comment: Thats why a staging and live server should be the same...are you sure the php versions are the same.. And can you show the code

Comment: I agree with you but i have diff scenario to have apache on staging and nginx on live ;-) don;t want break working thinks on staging